# Maven: No runnable methods on @ParameterizedTest

Tags: maven, kotlin, junit, parametrized-testing

I have a parameterized test, which is passing normally when running with IntelliJ run test configuration.

But running **`mvn test`** on it throws `java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods`.

All other non-parameterized tests marked with `@Test` pass normally both ways, but I am getting build failure because of this parameterized test.

I'll appreciate any help :)

Test:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource

internal class SampleTest {
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("samples")
    fun `should pass` (actual: String, expected: String) {
        // test body
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun samples() = listOf(
            Arguments.of("actual", "expected")
        )
    }
}
```

The error with `mvn test`:

```sh
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
        at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
```

My POM dependencies:

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

and build plugin:

```xml
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly I couldn't reproduce your problem, but here are a few things that might help you:

Use the latest surefire plugin. Add the following to the build/plugins in the pom

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
</plugin>
```

Add jupiter engine to your dependencies in the pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <version>RELEASE</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You've added junit-jupiter-api as your dependency three times, that might be a copypaste error.